# Python: `1+1j == (1+1j)` but `1+1j.imag == 2`, why?

Tags: python

It's very strange. Looks like python interpret it as `(1+1)j.imag`, but why? Shouldn't it be `1+(1j).imag` or `(1+1j).imag`?

Comment: There's no way it treats it as `(1+1)j`, that's not even valid. The `j` is not a postfix operator, it's part of a literal -- `1j` is a single token, an atom, an indivisible building stone of the Python grammar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's interpreting it as `1+(1j.imag)`, since [attribute access has a higher precedence than addition](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary).

Answer (score 3):

`1j` is a complex number literal. Like other literals in python, you can call methods on it and access its fields. `"hello".upper()` would be an analogous example for a string literal.

So, `1j` is a complex number (`type(1j)` returns `<class 'complex'>`). `1j.imag` is accessing the `imag` property of that number; the value of that property is (non-complex) 1.

1 + 1 = 2.

Answer (score 1):

That is not because of python but rather due to how the complex number maths is.

when you access (1j).imag => you are reading the imaginary part of 1j which is 1.
Hence it does the 1+1 = 2.

1+1j is 1 real + 1 imaginary.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

`1+1j` = `(1) + (1j)`

`1+1j.imag` = `(1) + (1j.imag)`

It is perfectly consistent.